Is a modification of an operation that preserves perfect graphs still valid?
Two adjacent vertices are referred to as neighbors of each other. The set of neighbors of a vertex $v$ is
called the open neighborhood of $v$ (or simply the neighborhood of v) and is denoted by $N(v)$. The set $N[v] = N(v) ∪ \{v\}$ is called the closed neighborhood
of $v$.
Let $G$ be a graph where $v \in V(G)$. Then the replication graph $R_v(G)$ of $G$ (with respect to $v$) is that graph obtained from $G$ by adding a new vertex $v'$ to $G$ and joining $v'$ to the vertices in the closed neighborhood $N_G(v)$.
In 1972, László Lovász obtained the following result.
Theorem 1 (The replication Lemma). Let $G$ be a graph where $v\in V(G)$. If $G$ is perfect, then $R_v(G)$ is perfect.
I'm curious, if I change the closed neighborhood in the replication
graph to an open neighborhood, what will happen in Theorem 1?  Is $R_v(G)$ still perfect?
Here's a more formal description: The opened replication graph $R'_v(G)$ of $G$ (with respect to $v$) is that graph obtained from $G$ by adding a new vertex $v'$ to $G$ and joining $v'$ to the vertices in the open neighborhood $N_G(v)$.
Problem 1. Let $G$ be a graph where $v\in V(G)$. If $G$ is perfect, then is $R'_v(G)$ perfect?

Aren't complete graphs counterexamples?

Sorry. If a vertex is added to a complete graph and then joined to the open neighborhood of that vertex, it is equivalent to removing an edge from a complete graph. They seem to be perfect.

Oh you are right. I am sorry

Then based on what I understand of the original proof, I think your hypothesis is correct

@VezenBU Yes, I feel that's correct.

For each induced subgraph:
(1) If $v'$ is not included, then it is an induced subgraph of the original graph and thus YES;
(2) If both $v'$ and $v$ are included, the clique number is the same as when $v'$ is removed, and $v'$ can just use the same color as $v$ so the chromatic number is also the same, so YES;
(3) If $v'$ is included and $v$ is not, the graph is the same as replacing $v'$ with $v$, so YES

Nice. Thank you, I also noticed that Lemma 8.1. 4 on page 321 of West's graph theory textbook is exactly what we need here. Furthermoe, I read Lovász's original tex（see https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(72)90006-4), and in fact, it obtains a stronger graph substitution that maintains  perfection.. Many books simplify it into one of the two forms I mentioned.
